# Is it possible to decode variable as nil if there's a type mismatch error

Tags: swift, codable

So basically what I want is for anytime that the API returns a type different than what the model expects to make that property nil.

For example:

```
struct Person {
var name: String?
var someType: String?
}
```

If the API returns a number for the someType property instead of a string I want to just make its value nil

I know I can do that implementing the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` initializer but then I'd have to set that up for every property of every response which would take a long time. Is there a better and quicker way?

Comment: Then you should use Any instead of String and let the consumer deal with different types.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own decodeIfPresent for Optional String and return nil if there is a type mismatch. This way you wont have to implement a custom initializer:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    public func decodeIfPresent(_ type: String.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> String? {
        do {
            return try decode(String.self, forKey: key)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch, DecodingError.keyNotFound {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let someType: String?
}
```

---

```
let json = #"{"name":"Steve","someType":1}"#
do {
    let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    person.name      // "Steve"
    person.someType  // nil
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: The first code is practically identically to just writing `try?` and your second code isn't using the `KeyedDecodingContainer` at all...

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Are you sure? it works for me

Comment: It's because you're using a extension to override an existing method. It's seriously bad practice. Also again, you could just write it as a single try? statement. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I am not overwriting anything. KeyedDecodingContainer is a struct not a class

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I am providing a solution for what is being asked. I wont delete my post just because of your opinion

Comment: @ClausJørgensen regarding your comment about override existing method it doesn'tt work.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63422823/2303865

Comment: Thanks Leo. It seems like a good solution and I see that it works on your code. Can't test on my project now because the server is down.

Comment: @JPAquino you are welcome

Comment: I have a question. When does your decodeIfPresent method gets called?

Comment: @LeoDabus so you're defining a extension, not calling it explicitly, but think it's not a problem that it's getting called?-) I guess this is what happens when you copy&paste answers from other questions :p

Comment: @ClausJørgensen NewDev learned this appraoch from one of my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/63803573/2303865

Comment: I suppose maybe we only get nil on the playground but on a real project that code would still throw a Type Mismatch error and not parse the response?

Comment: @JPAquino No. It does work. Take your time to test it. It doesn't matter if it is on playground or not.

Comment: @LeoDabus... actually from https://github.com/marksands/BetterCodable... which uses that approach too, but against their own custom type. So, I'm personally not a fan of an approach that holistically overrides a default behavior for a widely used type, and prefer the property wrapper approach

Comment: @NewDev I know already you prefer the property wrapper. I am answering what is being asked here. A way to avoid implementing a custom initializer.

Comment: @NewDev Btw if you use `try?` you will discard all Decoding errors. I've already showed you how to catch a specific error.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, Leo definitely didn't *just* copy-paste, so I think it's an unfounded accusation that doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @LeoDabus, it's not that I didn't know how to catch errors, but decided to simplify an answer to illustrate a concept. Perhaps it was an over-simplification - I should probably fix the other answer.